# rails, react-playerとhls.jsを用いてHLS再生の実装をしたい

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, 動画, hls

バックエンドにrailsを使用しており、フロントでreact/typescriptを用いている中で、[react-player](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player#readme)と[hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js)を用いたストリーミング再生機能の実装をしたいと考えています。

現状はvideoタグを用いて、Amazon S3においたmp4をcloudfront経由で取得して再生しています。

react-playerはhls.jsとも互換性がありそうですが、実装のイメージがつきません。
何か参考になる例などご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-player` は `hls.js` を内部で使用しています。必要に応じて CDN から `hls.js` をダウンロードして呼び出しています。

`hls.js` の設定を変更したい場合は、[Config prop](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player#config-prop) の `file.hlsOptions` などを設定すればよさそうです。

Comment: なるほど！ご丁寧な回答誠にありがとうございます！
その場合、<ReactPlayer url='ここにm3u8のurl'/>でhls.jsが呼び出されて再生されるという感じでしょうか。

Comment: @Kazk そうですね。そうなるはずです。